# Unable to convert json response to php variable

Tags: php, html, json

I need to convert json file and pass it to php variables so that i can store them in the database.

```
<?php
    //read the json file contents
    $fo=fopen("dealdetails.json","r");
    $fr=fread($fo,filesize("dealdetails.json"));
    $array=json_decode($fr,true);
    //$jsondata = file_get_contents('dealdetails.json');
     //convert json object to php associative array
    //$data = json_decode($jsondata, true);
    echo $array;
    echo $array['promo_id'];
    echo "json not printed";
?>
```

I tried both file_get_contents and fopen, fread

Output :

Arrayjson not printed

I am not getting the value for promo_id instead when i printed the $array i am getting output as Array.

Please suggest.  Thanks

Comment: Try doing a print_r($array);

Comment: @JasonK : thanks for the reply now i can see the whole array; what i should do to get those individual items and assign to php variables

Comment: look at the array closely. You may have to do a $array[0]['promo_id'];

Comment: @JasonK : Yes jason, it worked now; many thanks for that so there are multiple array elements right?

Comment: @JasonK : Got it jason, yes there are multiple array elements and i need to iterate for them to access.  Many thanks for your help

Comment: It depends on the json object is.